# How to play multiplayer Ticket to Ride (iOS/iPad) with friends over the Internet?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, online, ios

I am trying to play Ticket to Ride for the iOS on the iPad (regular full version, not pocket) with friends over the internet (not local wifi).
I tried using Game Center to issue a 'challenge', but it doesn't seem to work.  I always end up in a room with random players when I use the 'local' play feature.
Does anyone know if this type of multiplayer game is possible with the iOS TTR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to play with specific friends in real-time, though it may not be possible to play asynchronously. (Last time I tried, the game aborted if either my opponent or I left the TTR app, so it was real-time play only. That was a while ago though.)

Here's how to set it up.

For iPad:

1. On the main TTR screen (with Gerry the Conductor holding the ticket labeled Play!), click the "More..." gear.
2. On the next screen, click Online Games. This should automatically log you in to the online servers.
3. In the spiral notebook at the center of the screen, click either the Game Center tab (for your GC friends) or Buddies (friends you've marked in some version of online TTR - web or mobile).
4. Tap the name of one friend you want to play with. This will fly out a screen where you can choose the map and whether the game is ranked or not. Make your choices and hit the green Play button
5. A standard Game Center Multiplayer Game window will appear. It will default to a 4-player game, with you, the friend you selected, and 2 auto-match slots. You can delete slots (though in trying I had to remove my friend first and then could delete the auto-match slots) or add specific friends with the Invite Friend button. If you add, you'll be prompted for the message to send them. If they accept, the game will start.

For iPhone:

1. On the main TTR screen  (with Gerry the Conductor holding the ticket labeled Play!), click your playername in the upper right. (You may need to click on your player icon first to make it slide out).
2. Under the box with your playername and account #, click "Edit my profile" and then "Yes" to go to the Days Of Wonder site. This should automatically log you in to the online servers.
3. From the profile page, you should be able to add/delete buddies.